# Disabling keyframes

Tags: modeling, animation, keyframes

I am purely modeling things without using any animating features, such as inserting keyframes

Apparently I realised I accidentally inserted some keyframes after changing position of objects without knowing

Below are screenshots :
[image]

This is currently at 3rd frame; this is what I want for my final output. As you can see below there are some keyframes inserted

[image]

This is 38th frame and as you can see some of the objects slowly move to this position from where they were on the first image.

How can I make objects stay where they are on the first image? Can I disable the keyframe feature?

Thank you all always in advance

Comment: Copy the keyframe for the location you want it to stay in until you need it to move and put it right before the change

Comment: I think they're saying they didn't mean to animate at all, correct?